# What does China gain by being allied to/friendly with North Korea?

Tags: china, north-korea

China is North Korea's [largest trade partner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93North_Korea_relations#Trade) as well as their main contributor to foreign aid, it is clear that they are allied to/friendly with North Korea

What does China have to gain by being allied to/friendly with North Korea?

Comment: Its a non democratic neighbor whose power is negligible (by comparison with Russia for example). As seen by the Hong Kong protests the current government of China is not leaning towards a less authoritarian rule and has an aggressive expansionist strategy (South China Sea, Doklam, Taiwan, etc.). A post-war, likely democratic, North Korea would be a political and ideological torn. Also there are some historical reasons for their alliance given the similar choice of authoritarian socialism. Russia and China supported North Korea in the Korean War.

Comment: @armatita The Taiwan-China situation is not caused by "an aggressive expansionist strategy". Have you done your research?

Comment: @Will You mean its not a recent problem. True. The fact remains that Taiwan is an independent nation (for several decades now) not recognized by most countries because they want to continue doing trade with China. So let me put it in another way. I consider an agressive strategy of China not to officially recognize Taiwan independence even if they already are for all intents and purposes for the last 70 years. From the Chinese point of view Taiwan is a province. If that is not agressive, what is?

Comment: @armatita Republic of China (or Taiwan as you may call it) claims mainland China, Macau, Hong Kong, and Taiwan as parts of its territories (according to their constitution). Taiwan has never ever been a sovereignty or independent nation, so for either China (ROC or PRC), Taiwan is, de facto, a province.

Comment: @Will They stopped their claim over mainland China almost 20 years ago. In any case I wasn't comparing regimes (even though Taiwan is a democracy). China, as in PRC, [claims that the Republic of China government is illegitimate, referring to it as the "Taiwan Authority". **The ROC, however, with its own constitution, independently elected president and armed forces**, continues to view itself as the sole representative of China. The territory being controlled by the state has never been controlled by the PRC.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan#Political_and_legal_status)

Comment: @armatita They tried to create a new constitution, which excludes mainland China from its territory, but it failed. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_Republic_of_China#Suspension_of_the_constitution_and_martial_law)

Comment: @Will They failed to build a new constitution but the amendment to the old one was done just the same. That little trick you see at the end (Free are of the Republic of China) is another way of saying: this law is only applicable to territories we (as in Taiwan) control. Historically a large part of Taiwan still considers itself the "real" Chinese, thus the whole vanity description. Will, the mainland China (today PRC) has no real authority over Taiwan for decades.  The US went there on the onset of the Korean war and stopped PRC from invading. The division has remained ever since.

Comment: @armatita There's no such amendment either. I've gone thru all the amendments they've done since 1991 [Amendments](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E8%8F%AF%E6%B0%91%E5%9C%8B%E6%86%B2%E6%B3%95#.E6.86.B2.E6.B3.95.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.80.E6.AC.A1.E5.A2.9E.E4.BF.AE). I'm not trying to deny your point where the PRC has no authority over Taiwan currently. I'm merely trying to tell you a fact that Taiwan (the island) is not independent under any circumstances.

Comment: Look @Will you seem to be in the US so if give any credit to your own institutions (US Department of State) you'll find that information easily enough and I quote:  [the authorities on Taiwan in 1991 abandoned their claim of governing mainland China, stating that they do not "dispute the fact that the P.R.C. controls mainland China](https://2009-2017.state.gov/outofdate/bgn/taiwan/2813.htm). As for your colorful description of independence I should probably point out that I follow the [common interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence) of it.  Lets just agree to disagree.

Comment: @armatita "the authorities on Taiwan in 1991 abandoned their claim of governing mainland China" does not mean they have changed the constitution. At the time, the president of ROC was a member of Democratic Progressive Party which is pro independence. You seem a reasonable guy but why cant you just get over yourself and admit that you made a mistake? Right this moment, the constitution of ROC still have the article claiming mainland China as its territory. Why is that so hard to grasp?

Comment: China is not so much friendly to NK, but more fearful of it. If you have a gangster in your neighborhood, you sure will try not to anger them. If they ask you for five bucks occasionally, you'd probably give it to them.

Comment: @xuq01 Not if the gangster was twenty times smaller than you

Comment: @Charlie What if the gangster has an automatic rifle (i.e., nuclear weapons)? You might have better (and more) firearms than the thug, but if they fire first, they'll still kill you (or at lest very badly wound you). After all, if NK didn't have nuclear weapons, no one would be really concerned even if China is actually friendly with NK.

Answer (score 13):

China likes a barrier between US-allied territory and itself. 
Before North Korea was the nuclear threat it is today, it was the barrier that the Chinese government wanted.

And I think that China believes that they can make North Korea back into the (somewhat) peaceful 'barrier' if they keep giving them aid and buying stuff from them. Or at least they believe that North Korea won't attack them if they stay 'relatively friendly'.

China may also see solidarity with North Korea regarding shared hardships that both of them have gone through, such as WWII Japanese occupation, or US embargoes during their socialism days.

Another possible reason is that apparently China is fearful of refugees fleeing North Korea and going into China if the Kim regime falls. In that regard, they'd rather preserve the status quo, though they'd definitely rather turn North Korea into the 'barrier' again.

Comment: Same reason why Russia freaks out when NATO talks about Poland or Ukraine joining the club, or the USA with Cuba as a potential Soviet Union base in the 1960s. Physical/geographic buffers with perceived enemies = good.

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as in the relations of the enemy of the enemy.

Looking back at the Korean War, it is not difficult to find the war might have been extended to China if it had not been limited in North Korea. That is the reason China began their assistance to that country. Then came the Cold War, when communist (socialist) countries and capitalist countries formed their respective blocs, and since North Korea and China are self-claimed socialist countries, they have to bond together to establish their images to the world.

In today's China, young people who are influenced by western cultures not less than those who live in the west do not like North Korea as does their own government. And time and again China has felt the small neighbor is out of its control. Kim Jung Un hasn't even paid a visit to China since he came into power 5 years ago, and the distance of the two countries is so close.It is obvious that he does not respect China but that China has no other better approach for the time being to handle this country than maintain the existing relationship.

Answer (score 1):

What CCP gains with N Korea? (CCP is not China and China is not CCP)

1. North Korea doesn't produce K-pop, a threat to CCP as example non communist produced culture and a most valuable export.
2. North Korea is friendly and dependent communist country at the border.
3. No powerful economic competitor like an unified Korea at the border.
4. No working example of a democracy right on its border for the people of China. CCP is already struggling to fend off K-pop.
5. No Voice of America or BBC broadcasting right on its border

Comment: They don't produce K-Pop!?! Is that seriously a relevant political reason?

Comment: @Philipp It is indeed relevant. If foreign culture was not a threat to the CCP's power, China would not need The Great Firewall, and would not go out of their way to censor K-POP directly https://www.scmp.com/magazines/style/celebrity/article/3147814/how-will-chinas-strict-new-entertainment-rules-affect-k
 The US's success in the cold war is largely attributed to winning the culture war, and indeed the U.S. DOD helped Hollywood become the global influence it is today for that reason. https://bura.brunel.ac.uk/bitstream/2438/14791/4/FullText.pdf

Answer (score -2):

The same advantage the US has on the other side. *Divide and rule*.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/44297)

Comment: @Alexei From the Chinese point of view this is a very good reason. All the empires and great powers over the world always relied on this to maintain their position.